# Convergence of a sequence with repeated sines

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ and $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined recursively as follows:
$$
a_0=x, \quad \text{and} \quad a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n).
$$ 
Show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\,a_n^2}=3.
$$

Note. There is a very strong numerical evidence that the above is valid, and the limit is independent of the initial choice of $a_0$. I have no idea where to start from.

Comment: You probably want to exclude $\pi$ from the allowed starting values ;)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I meant $x\in(0,\pi/2)$! It is now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotics of $a_n$ are completely analyzed in [de Bruijn's book](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/8f38bda7-c914-4c19-bb78-d411de0bb8d6/167a04a1d7c8d16e8b2fe44080830f57), p. 157, from which this follows immediately.